# Can't scroll 3 TableViews in a parent ScrollView, even though I used the nestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, tableview

I've got 3 TableViews(third party library I found on GitHub) on my activity. It's in a scrollable parent view ... I used the nestedScrollView to enable scrolling in my TableViews but it doesn't work... it turns dark and data doesn't get displayed... please help 
Reply

the library I used :
 //TableView library
    compile 'de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:2.8.0'

Code snippet - I removed the ScrollView and the multiples nestedScrollViews due to the fact that I had a deadline to release my app and was forced to do without :

```
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#2979ff"
            android:id="@+id/driver_money_double"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/tableOneBackColor"
            android:id="@+id/yyy"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="FARE 1"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <de.codecrafters.tableview.TableView xmlns:table="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/summary_table_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </de.codecrafters.tableview.TableView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/tableTwoBackColor"
            android:id="@+id/xxx"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="FARE 2"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

        <de.codecrafters.tableview.TableView
            xmlns:table="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/summary_table_two"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/tableThreeBackColor"
            android:id="@+id/zzz"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Combination"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

        <de.codecrafters.tableview.TableView
            xmlns:table="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/summary_table_three" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#d84315"
                android:id="@+id/Money_hand"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Change in Hand   R"
                android:textColor="#fafafa"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#d84315"
                android:id="@+id/change_money_double"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#fafafa"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ama_ads"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub4444444">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You probably should specify what's your library and then post short and relevant snippets of your code for others to read and debug. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have done so sir

Comment: Why don't you use https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView. It's much better.